# Jquery - multiple selectors - get elements in sequence

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="a1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="b2"/>
<select name="c"><option value="c3" selected="true"/></select>
<input type="text" name="d" value="d4"/>
</form>
```

Now, I want to get list of all input and select elements in the form

```
  var mydata = new Array();
  $('#myform').find('input, select').each(function ()
  {
    mydata.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Result I am getting is: a1, b2, d4, c3
But what I want to get is: a1,b2,c3,d4 (in the same sequence as displayed in UI).

Note: I can give some dummy class (say: mydatafields) to all the input and select elements and use:

```
$('mydatafields').forEach()
```

something like, but I am checking if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working the way you intend in Chrome & IE 9 - http://jsfiddle.net/P5pAY/1/. What browser are you using (not sure it makes a difference)?

Comment: Also, what version of jQuery are you using? @JamesHill's fiddle shows the same error you're having for jQuery 1.2.6, but works for later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is by adding a temporary attribute (e.g class name) to your elements, then loop through each element, and finally remove it.

```
var mydata = [];
$('#myform').find('input, select').addClass('temporaryClassName');
$('.temporaryClassName').each(function() {
    mydata.push($(this).val());
}).removeClass('temporaryClassName');
```

An alternative method consists of selecting ever input element using `:input`, and filter the desired elements. For this example, filtering is not strictly needed. I have included the line for educative purposes.

```
var mydata = [];
$('#myform').find('input, select').each(function() {
    if(!/^input|select$/i.test(this.nodeName)) return; //Filter non-input/select
    mydata.push($(this).val());
});
alert(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

try :input selector. It should consider them all as inputs

Answer (score 0):

you do not need jquery for this.... here is a non-jquery approach to the problem.

```
var arr = [];
window.onload = function() {
    getChildElements(document.getElementById("myform"), arr);
    console.log(arr);
};

function getChildElements(element, arr) {
    var elements = element.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type == "select-one") {
            getChildElements(elements[i], arr);
        } else if (elements[i].nodeType == 1) {
            arr.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

however if you **wanted it to work with jquery** just change the *elements* definition with...

```
var elements = element.childNodes || element[0].childNodes;
```